# Question about $\mathbb{C}$-linear and $\mathbb{R}$-linear mapping.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

For the following question:

> Let $X$ be a vector space $\mathbb{C}$; let $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ satisfy $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$. We say that $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$-linear if $f(tx)=tf(x)$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$, and it is $\mathbb{C}$-linear if $f(tx)=tf(x)$ for all $t\in \mathbb{C}$.  Denote the identity map on $X$ by id.  Let $E$ and $F$ be complex vector spaces.  Assume that $u:E\rightarrow F$ is $\mathbb{C}$-linear and $v:F\rightarrow E$ is $\mathbb{R}$-linear and $u\circ v=id$. Prove that there exists a $\mathbb{C}$-linear map $w:F\rightarrow E$ such that $u\circ w=id$

I would like some clarification on how the question defines the mappings $u$ and $v$ and also ways to tackle the question.

Suppose we let $z\in \mathbb{C}$ where $z=a+ib$, and $u$ is a $\mathbb{C}-linear$ mapping between complex vector spaces $E$ to $F$, and let $t\in \mathbb{R}$ and $v$ is a $\mathbb{R}-linear$ mapping between the complex vector spaces $F$ to $E$, then $u(zx)=u((a+ib)x)=(a+ib)u(x)$ and $v(tx)=tv(x)$.

The composition of for $u\circ v = x=id$, taking into account of scalar multiplication, would mean that:

$(u\circ (zv))(tx)=u(z(v(tx)))=u(z(tv(x)))=u((a+ib)(tv(x)))=u((at+itb)v(x))=(at+itb)(u(v(x)))=x.$  (1)

The question ask for a $\mathbb{C}=linear$ mapping $w$ such that $u \circ w=x=id$, again taking into account of scalar multiplication, as before for $u$, let $z\in \mathbb{C}$ where $z=a+ib$ and also for $w$ let $p\in \mathbb{C}$ where $p=m+in$, then $u(zx)=zu(x)=(a+ib)u(x)$, similarly, $w(px)=pw(x)=(m+in)w(x)$.  So for the composition mapping $u\circ w=x=id$.  
Taking into account again scalar multiplication, $u\circ (zw))=(px)=u(z(w(px)))=u(zp(w(x)))=zu(p(w(x)))=zpu(w(x))=(a+ib)(m+in)u(w(x))=(am+ian+ibm-bn)u(w(x))=x$.  (2)

Since (1) and (2) are equal, we equate coefficients, we have 
$at=am-bn$ 
$bt=an+bm$

I am not sure if i am going along the right path.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: You already know that $u$ is a surjective $\mathbb{C}$-linear mapping. It remains to show that it is an injective $\mathbb{C}$-linear mapping, and this can be reduced to $\text{Ker}(u)=0$. Once you have done this, $u$ is invertible, and the existence follows

Comment: @Caffeine sorry for my late response.  I am still confused about one thing in light of your comment.  The question states that $u$ maps between vector space s $E$ and $F$, How can I infer that that $u$ is like $f$ in terms of domain and range. Basically $f$ is a linear functional and unless the vector spaces $E, F, and X$ are finite dimensional, then there is no way it can automatically be inferred that $u$ is a surjective map.  Onto is pretty easy to show though.

Comment: The $\mathbb{C}$ linearity of a function between two complex vector spaces is defined (and I think that's what is intended in the text) by the same equation $f(tx)=tf(x)$, only now $tf(x)$ has to be intended as scalar multiplication. Indeed, that's how you define linear maps between vector spaces on the same field $\mathbb{K}$, without any need of conditions on dimensionality of domain and codomain.

Comment: @Caffeine do you mean because $f(tx)=tf(x)$ and $tf(x)\in F$, it is assume then that $F$ is a vector space of dimension one, I mean implicitly of course.

Comment: It is not assumed that $\text{dim}(F)=1$. As an example, think of this: $f:\mathbb{C}^2\to \mathbb{C}^2; (x,y)\to (x+y,x-y)$. This mapping is $\mathbb{C}$ linear ($f(t(x,y))=(tx+ty,tx-ty)=t(x+y,x-y)=tf(x,y)$) but $\text{dim}(F)=2$

Comment: @Caffeine in your example of $f:(t(x,y))$, it is not automatically onto.  Am I correct?  Because the way I learned about linear functional, it is defined as $f:X\rightarrow F$, where $F$ is both a vector space and a field of dimension one.

Comment: this is not a linear functional, it's a linear mapping. As I said, there's a definition of $\mathbb{C}$ linearity for those maps too, and I thought that the text was referring to those (since it didn't specify $F=\mathbb{C}$, which is necessary for $u$ to be a functional)

Comment: @Caffeine did you arrive at the mapping being subjective by inferring that $F=\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105177/discussion-between-caffeine-and-seth-mai).

Comment: @Caffeine I am in chat right now.  I just saw this.  My apologies.

Comment: @Caffeine thank you so much for your help.  I appreciate you taking the time out to respond to my questions.  :)